# Get text value of html elements with same #Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a id="s_6_2_19_0_mb" class="siebui-ctrl-drilldown" name="Name" rowid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">00102400010630001</a>
<a id="s_6_2_19_0_mb" class="siebui-ctrl-drilldown" name="Name" rowid="2" href="javascript:void(0)">00102402608820001</a>
```

I need to get the text values of both these elements. so I use the following code:

```
$('a#s_6_2_19_0_mb[rowid="1"]').text();
$('a#s_6_2_19_0_mb[rowid="2"]').text();
```

But the #Id will differ from page to page. So I am getting the id in a variable, say "idVal". And idVal = s_6_2_19_0_mb. So now to get the text value I used the below code

```
$('\'a' +'#'+idVal+'\[rowid\=\"1\"]'+'\'').text();
```

But this throws me an error. Please let me know how to extract the text value using a variable for #id in the above case

Comment: Same ID??? IDs should be always unique.

Comment: you have a syntax error, try this: `$('a' +'#'+idVal+'[rowid="1"]').text();`

Comment: What error? Also ID must be unique (you can't access second element with same ID)

Comment: Yes, should never have same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simplify your selector and remove the `a` and use the following code where `rowId` holds the id of the row you wish to retrieve:

```
var linkText = $('#'+ idVal +'[rowid=\"'+ rowId +'\"]').text();
```

or just hardcode the row id like that:

```
var link1Text = $('#'+ idVal +'[rowid="1"]').text();
var link1Text = $('#'+ idVal +'[rowid="2"]').text();
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Well, as others have said **IDs must be unique**, but if you **really** can't change that (and assuming classes and rows may differ), then you could do:

```
$("a[id='"+idVal+"'][rowid='1']").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Id be unique in HTML** so use class instead of id

```
$(".siebui-ctrl-drilldown[rowid = 1]").text();
$(".siebui-ctrl-drilldown[rowid = 2]").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the =, nor the "s, and you have an uneven number of quotes.
So you should have something like this:

```
$('a' +'#'+idVal+'[rowid="1"]').text();
```

Oh and yeah, as everybody else said, IDs should always be unique. Trying to access multiple elements with the same ID will always return the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have same IDs for multiple elements on same page. however You can use class selector to target them:

```
$("a.siebui-ctrl-drilldown[rowid=1]").text();
$("a.siebui-ctrl-drilldown[rowid=2]").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
 $('a#' + idVal + '[rowid="1"]').text();
```

However you have to avoid same id in DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:(Remove ids with same value)

```
$("a[rowid=1]").text();
$("a[rowid=2]").text();
```