# How can I get the same id (slides) as array through javascript without using **jquery**, **querySelectorAll()** Method or **querySelector()** Method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```html
<h1 id="slides">Her Name</h1>
<h1 id="slides">Was</h1>
<h1 id="text">All is OK</h1>
<h1 id="slides">Mamedul</h1>
<h1 id="photos"><img src="rrr.jpg"/></h1>
<h1 id="text">, but I am</h1>
```

How can I get the same id (slides) as array through javascript without using **jquery**, **querySelectorAll()** Method or **querySelector()** Method?

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique in a document. Use classes if you want to get multiple elements with same class name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text value of html elements with same #Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045679/get-text-value-of-html-elements-with-same-id)

Comment: You most have only one `h1` element and `id` attributes in you document should be unique

Comment: I know that it is possible with same classes but document.getElementsByClassName("slides") is not support with IE9- browsers. So, I want this. Do you realize me Mr. @RohitAgrawal?

Comment: Thanks to Mr. @YosvelQuintero. Pls. see my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

use classes instead of using same id's

```
<h1 class="slides">Her Name</h1>
<h1 class"slides">Was</h1>
<h1 class="text">All is OK</h1>
<h1 class="slides">Mamedul</h1>
<h1 class="photos"><img src="rrr.jpg"/></h1>
<h1 class="text">, but I am</h1>
```

then you can use class selector

```
$('.slides')
```

Comment: sir, do you read the post carefully? I didn't want to using jquery. Are you realize me, sir?